# Batch processing of GDAL clip function

Tags: raster, gdal, clip, extents

When I am trying to batch process GDAL clipping in QGIS 2.18 with 30 raster files I get the following Error:

> GDAL command output:
>
> ERROR 1: Cannot compute bounding box of cutline.

My coordinate systems are all the same. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Do the process clipping in QGIS 3.6. This did the trick at my data.